# (eclipse) cloned repository project missing gen folder

Tags: java, eclipse, git, xtext

I cloned this: [git repository](https://github.com/vorburger/xtext-sandbox) into eclipse workspace. I am interested in **Xtext-XML** sample only. 
Because i want to create a domain specfic language generating xml code. Thats seems the only example at this topic.

My problem is that on the build path the '/src-gen' folders are missing.
All the projects have a red exclamation mark in the package explorer. How can i generate those missing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [README.TXT](https://github.com/vorburger/xtext-sandbox/blob/master/Xtext-XML/org.eclipse.xtext.example.fowlerdsl/README.TXT) file. There it says:

> Start a new Eclipse Application and create an empty Java project.
>   Add new source folder called "src-gen/" and put the following statemachine into a file in the "src/" folder.

```
 // MrsGrantsSecretCompartments.statemachine

 events
        doorClosed        D1CL
        drawOpened        D2OP
        lightOn                L1ON
        doorOpened        D1OP
        panelClosed PNCL
end

resetEvents
        doorClosed
end

commands
        unlockPanel PNUL
        lockPanel        PNLK
        lockDoor        D1LK
        unlockDoor        D1UL
end

state idle
        actions {unlockDoor lockPanel}
        doorClosed = active
end

state active
        drawOpened         = waitingForLight
        lightOn                = waitingForDraw
end

state waitingForLight
        lightOn = unlockedPanel
end

state waitingForDraw
        drawOpened = unlockedPanel
end

state unlockedPanel
        actions {unlockPanel lockDoor}
        panelClosed = idle
end
```

Comment: ok thanks, that worked. But it didn't produce what i exprected ;)I thought the result would be an XML file in src-gen folder, but i see an java file only???

Comment: Can't help you with that, as I know neither Xtext nor the specific example. Now that it compiles though, I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out, maybe using the Xtext documentation here: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html